# MDCard covers its content, problem with kivyMD inheritance

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I created this widget in a .kv file that inherits from MDCard:

```
<ElementCard@MDCard>:
  radius: '10dp'
  spacing: '10dp'
  padding: '10dp'
  image: ''
  text: ''
  sub_text: ''
  orientation: 'vertical'
  md_bg_color: 0.87, 0, 0.49
  ripple_behavior: True # effect
  on_release:
    app.root.transition = RiseInTransition()
  Image: 
    source: root.image
    halign: 'center'
  MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    md_bg_color: 'green'
    MDLabel:
      text: root.text
      color: 'white'
      halign: 'center'
    MDLabel:
      text: root.sub_text
      halign: 'center'
```

and I use it:

```
<ui>:
...

  ElementCard:
    text: 'IA'
    sub_text: 'Inteligencia artificial'
    image: 'images/image1.jpg'
    on_release: 
      root.current = 'screen1'
...
```

The problem is that the ElementCard widget doesn't show the content:
[ElementCard is the purple block and it covers all its content.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFx8z.jpg)

When I set the transparency in 0.5 the program looks like this:
[50% transparency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4blK.jpg)

The versions are these:

Kivy==2.1.0

kivymd==1.1.1

I've tried rebooting the machine, restarting the virtual environment, reinstalling kivy and kivymd but nothing works.

I think the problem is the inheritance because when I use directly the MDCard like in this code:

```
        MDCard:
          radius: '10dp'
          spacing: '10dp'
          padding: '10dp'
          orientation: 'vertical'
          md_bg_color: 0.87, 0, 0.49,0.6
          ripple_behavior: True # effect
          on_release:
            app.root.transition = RiseInTransition()
          Image: 
            source: 'images/image1.jpg'
            halign: 'center'
          MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            md_bg_color: 'green'
            MDLabel:
              text: 'IA'.
              color: 'white'
              halign: 'center'
            MDLabel:
              text: 'Inteligencia artificial'
              halign: 'center'
```

With the last code the program works fine:
[MDCard works normally.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGvCA.jpg)

main.py full code:

```python
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class Ui(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style ='Dark'
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette ='Teal'
        Builder.load_file("design.kv")
        return Ui()
    def change_style(self, checked, value):
        if value:
            self.theme_cls.theme_style ='Dark'
            pass
        else:
            self.theme_cls.theme_style ='Light'
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

design.kv full code:

```
#:kivy 2.1.0
#:import RiseInTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.RiseInTransition
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

<CustomizeScreen@MDBoxLayout>:
  orientation: 'vertical'
  text: ''
  padding: 100
  MDLabel: 
    text: root.text
    halign: 'center'
    pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5}
  
  MDFillRoundFlatButton: 
    text: 'REGRESAR'
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
    on_release: 
      app.root.current = 'screen_principal'
      app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction = 'left')

<ElementCard@MDCard>:
  radius: '10dp'
  spacing: '10dp'
  padding: '10dp'
  image: ''
  text: ''
  sub_text: ''
  orientation: 'vertical'
  md_bg_color: 0.87, 0, 0.49
  ripple_behavior: True # effect
  on_release:
    app.root.transition = RiseInTransition()
  Image: 
    source: root.image
    halign: 'center'
  MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    md_bg_color: 'green'
    MDLabel:
      text: root.text
      color: 'white'
      halign: 'center'
    MDLabel:
      text: root.sub_text
      halign: 'center'

<ui>:
  MDScreen:
    name: 'screen_principal'
    md_bg_color: "black"
    MDBoxLayout: 
      orientation: "vertical"
      MDBoxLayout: 
        size_hint: 1, 0.2 # x=1 ocupa todo, y=0.2 ocupa 20%
        orientation: "horizontal"
        padding: '10dp'
        MDCard:
          radius: '10dp'
          padding: '10dp'
          line_color: 1,0,1,1
          MDLabel: 
            text: 'APLICACIÓN DE TECNOLOGÍA'
            halign: 'center'
            pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.5}
          MDSwitch: 
            pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.5}
            on_active:
              app.change_style(*args)

      MDGridLayout: 
        cols: 3
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.8 # x=1 ocupa todo, y=0.8 ocupa 80%
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
        padding: ['10dp','10dp','10dp','10dp']
        spacing: '10dp'

        ElementCard:
          text: 'IA'
          sub_text: 'Inteligencia artificial'
          image: 'images/image1.jpg'
          on_release: 
            root.current = 'screen1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I commented this problem in the github kivyMD project, they marked as a bug and give me a couple of options to implement, [link to github](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/1430)

Edit: 
Thanks for pointing out my mistake with my link.

This is the first option:

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard

KV = """
<ElementCard>

    MDLabel:
        text: "HELLO WORLD"


MDScreen:

    ElementCard:
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.8 
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        md_bg_color: 0.87, 0, 0.49, 1
"""


class ElementCard(MDCard):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


MainApp().run()
```

and the 2nd:

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard

KV = """
<ElementCard@MDCard>

    MDLabel:
        text: "HELLO WORLD"


MDScreen:

    ElementCard:
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.8 
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        md_bg_color: 0.87, 0, 0.49, 1
"""


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


MainApp().run()
```

I guess that the kivymd developers will repair this bug in the future.

Comment: Link-only answers have risk of link going dead. Please consider providing summary/steps from link to solve the problem.