# Kivy don't draw the mesh

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, kivy, mesh, kivymd

Its my problem, I'm mading a chart in kivymd, and I will fill inside the line, but my problem is... when I draw inside canvas, the mesh don't show anything:

[image: List with empty filling]

Don't is problem with the vertices or indices, because I put inside another basic program, and the mesh works:

[image: Vertices and Indices test]

I think that is because the kv language, but I have no problems mading the same mesh, with the same arguments, inside another program. 
The Line was drawed, so don't have any problem with something cleaning the canvas. 
I tried to remove the MDCard before the widget from the canvas, because I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74793428/mdcard-covers-its-content-problem-with-kivymd-inheritance), but it don't solved too. 
Another think is that I debug the code, and inside the canvas.before class have the Mesh

I really doesn't have any idea about what the cause from this issue...

If it help, this is the widget hierarchy:

MDApp: 
-MDBoxLayout: 
--LineChart(MDBoxLayout): (My chart widget) 
---MDGridLayout: 
----MDBoxLayout: (Here stay the labels y) 
----MDCard: 
-----MDFloatLayout: (Where the graph was drawed) 
----MDFloatLayout: (Its only a widget to fill the empty cell) 
----MDBoxLayout: (Here stay the labels x) \

**EDITED**

Before a time, and a lot of tries, I paste my code inside the code that works, and I notted that don't works. It's my code resumided:

```py
'''
Mesh test
=========

This demonstrates the use of a mesh mode to distort an image. You should see
a line of buttons across the bottom of a canvas. Pressing them displays
the mesh, a small circle of points, with different mesh.mode settings.
'''

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Mesh, Color
from functools import partial
from math import cos, sin, pi


class MeshTestApp(App):

    def change_mode(self, mode, *largs):
        self.mesh.mode = mode

    def build_mesh(self):
        """ returns a Mesh of a rough circle. """
        gp = [52.0, 49.0, 236.5, 166.0, 421.0, 283.0, 605.5, 400.0, 790.0, 517.0, 790.0, 49.0, 52.0, 49.0]
        ver = []
        idc = []
        for idx in range(0, len(gp), 2):
            idc.append(idx // 2)
            ver.extend([gp[idx], gp[idx + 1], 0, 0])
        print(ver)
        print(idc)
        return Mesh(vertices=ver, indice=idc)

    def build(self):
        wid = Widget()
        with wid.canvas:
            Color(.5, .5, .5, 1)
            self.mesh = self.build_mesh()

        layout = BoxLayout(size_hint=(1, None), height=50)
        for mode in ('points', 'line_strip', 'line_loop', 'lines',
                'triangle_strip', 'triangle_fan'):
            button = Button(text=mode)
            button.bind(on_release=partial(self.change_mode, mode))
            layout.add_widget(button)

        root = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        root.add_widget(wid)
        root.add_widget(layout)

        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MeshTestApp().run()
```

Its interesting, that the simplest thinks can miss from our vision. My error is it:

> Mesh(vertices=ver, indice=idc)

I passed a argument `indice`, but the argument is `indices`.